# Why my while loops doesn't recognize the condition of the integer and make infinite loop? (Java while loops "Validate a bank Pin")

Tags: java, loops, oop, while-loop, do-while

I have tried inputing the same **int** as the *validPin* variable, but it makes infinite loop even though  the condition is already true. Also, I have tried to change *validPin* to 12345 and it worked, but if the *validPin* is 002200 it doesnt work. Why?

```
public void main() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int validPin = 002200;
    System.out.print("Enter PIN to access:");
    int pin = in.nextInt();


    while (pin != validPin) {
        System.out.print("Invalid PIN, Try again:");
        pin = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("You have entered the correct PIN, now you have acces for your account!");

}
```

}

Comment: `002200` is `2200` for an int, did you try it? Maybe you should use strings instead primitive integers

Answer (score 3):

In Java source code, 002200 is the decimal value 1152, and for nextInt, 002200 is the decimal value 2200.

(This is an annoying throwback from C that should never have been adopted in Java, but we're stuck with it).

Read about octal constants in Java source code - any tutorial should have this information.

Also, if you require the user to actually type those leading zeroes, you may be better off using strings rather than ints.